# How to open all files grep finds containing a certain text, recursive

Tags: macos, grep, xargs

I type

```
grep -r 'something' .
```

and grep finds a lot of hits.

Now I want to open all files that were found.

I try

```
grep -r 'something' . | xargs vim
```

nothing happens.

Comment: Does your `grep` spit out the names of the files with the hits?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ?! :)

```
grep -rl 'something' . | xargs vim
```

or

```
vim "$(grep -rl 'something' .)"
```

> -l, --files-with-matches
> Suppress  normal  output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  Scanning each input file stops upon first match.

Comment: thanks but neither works.

Comment: It should. Wrong directory or pattern

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no special characters in your files (like newlines), try this:

```
grep -lr 'something' . | xargs bash -c 'vim "$@" < /dev/tty' _
```